# Tree structure in react-admin

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

I want to represent my nested data in **tree structure**. Is there any way to show nested data in tree view using `react-admin`?

Answer (score 2):

Although experimental you can have a look on this plugin: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-tree-ui-materialui

It seems that nested data should be of the same resource (e.g categories and subcategories) and not different ones as someone might wish it supported

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You'll have to create a custom React component for that.